# bash script to move files from deep directory structure

Tags: bash

I would like to be able to move files to a directory (eg Desktop/tbb) from a directory structure where each file is kept deep in the structure in different folders.

The directory structure  with the files I want is like this:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/SeqS/Plots/Results/FTF/freak/5M/5M_T1/SNAPSHOT/CN/Jimbob/LP7005321bam_ratio.txt

/Users/me/Desktop/SeqS/Plots/Results/FTF/freak/5M/5M_T2/SNAPSHOT/CN/Salad/LP9904920bam_ratio.txt

/Users/me/Desktop/SeqS/Plots/Results/FTF/freak/5M/5M_T3/SNAPSHOT/CN/Spags/LP6005334bam_ratio.txt
```

To move all of them to 
    /Desktop/tbb

Is there a way of asking in bash to search for example for all files that end in ...bam_ratio.txt within a folder and it to search folders within that to retrieve the correct files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` command.  It's different in different versions of bash, but it looks something like this.

```
find /Users/me/Desktop/SeqS/Plots/Results/FTF/freak/ -type f -name "*bam_ratio.txt" -exec mv {} /Desktop/tbb/ \;
```

Comment: Lovely. Did the job. I particularly like the exec function allowing me to use the results of find

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find` command to find the files you want, e.g.:

```
find . -type f -iname "*bam_ratio.txt"
```

Will find all files ending in 'bam_ratio.txt' in the current directory.

To move them to your desired directory you can use the `-exec` flag like:

```
find . -type f -iname "*bam_ratio.txt" -exec mv {} ~/Desktop/tbb/ \;
```